# prove this identity $\sin(x+y)\sin(x-y)=\sin^2 x - \sin^2 y$

Tags: trigonometry

prove this identity :
$$\sin(x+y)\sin(x-y)=\sin^2 x - \sin^2 y$$
 I tried solving it with additional formulas but I can't get the right answer. I get 
$$\sin^2 x \cos^2 y-\cos^2 x \sin^2 y$$

Comment: Do you want a geometrical proof or just a proof using some common facts like $\sin^2+\cos^2=1$?

Comment: I think common facts

Comment: Do you know the formulas for $\sin(x\pm y)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\sin^2 x \cos^2 y-\cos^2 x \sin^2 y=\sin^2 x(1-\sin^2 y) -(1-\sin^2 x) \sin ^2 y$

$=\sin^2 x -\sin^2 x\sin^2y -\sin ^2 y + \sin^2x\sin^2y$

$=\sin^2 x - \sin ^2 y$

Answer (score 1):

Use the identity $$\sin(x\pm y)=\sin x\cos y\pm \sin y\cos x$$
and we can get 
\begin{align*}
LHS&=\sin(x+y)\sin(x-y)\\
&=(\sin x\cos y+\cos x\sin y)(\sin x\cos y-\cos x\sin y)\\
&=\sin^2x\cos^2y-\cos^2x\sin^2y \\
\end{align*}

See if you can take it from here using the identity $$\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1.$$